# Как сделать, чтобы процедура всегда компилировась с заданным уровнем оптимизации?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Eсть PL/SQL-процедура с большой интенсивностью вычислений. Если она не скомпилирована с уровнем оптимизации 3 (по умолчанию установленно 2), то ее производительность заметно ниже.

Как сделать, чтобы процедура всегда компилировалась с уровнем оптимизации не ниже 3?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How can I make sure a PL/SQL program is compiled with optimization turned on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49799661) от участника [@Steven Feuerstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4403757/steven-feuerstein)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/49799661

Answer (score 2):

В этом случае надо воспользоваться [условной компиляцией](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-DC23291F-006D-49C4-87DA-6B31F19F162A), а точнее, директивой `ERROR`.

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
create or replace procedure computation is
begin
    $IF $$plsql_optimize_level < 3 $THEN
        $ERROR 'This procedure must be compiled with plsql_optimize_level=3 or higher!' $END
    $END
    for n in 1..10e6 loop null; end loop; 
end computation;
/
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
4/9       PLS-00179: $ERROR: This procedure must be compiled with plsql_optimize_level=3 or higher!

alter session set plsql_optimize_level=3
/
alter procedure computation compile
/
exec computation 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49799662/6571020) от участника [@Steven Feuerstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4403757/steven-feuerstein)</sub>